# Backbone Uncaught TypeError: Object render has no method 'call'

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

So I have this method and the error occurs when I set the model to have newDataToShow-

```
addDatumToShow: function(e){
    var test = $(".datum-list").find(":checked");
    newDataToShow = [];
    _.each(test, function(value,key,list){
        var title = $(value).data("title");
        newDataToShow.push(title);
    });
    this.model.set('dataToShow', newDataToShow);
},
```

This is how I'm passing in the model -

```
this.rightView = new app.TableView({model: flowerModel});
```

and this is how I'm creating the model-

```
var flowerModel = new app.DataModel({title: "flower", values: ["tulip","rose","dandelion"], dataToShow:["tulip", "rose", "dandelion"], data: data});
```

Why am I getting the error -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object render has no method 'call'
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whats exactly causing this problem, but can you debug and check the value of test variable?

I think you could try doing something like this

`var test = $('.datum').has(':checked');`

And let your rest of your code be as it is.

Comment: Why do you recommend to use `.is('checked')`? `.is` returns a **boolean** whereas the OPs seems to want a jQuery object. Furthermore, `is('checked')` will *always* return `false`, because there is no element with tag name `checked` in HTML.

Comment: I asume that you are trying to assign value to test variable from a radio or checkbox input control, and this is any day a better approach for doing that. The point here is what is the value in the test variable?

Comment: I m sorry that should have been $('.datum').has(':checked') and checkex is an attribute and not an html tag